# How to change the image of the fabric.Image object attribute src?

Tags: fabricjs

How can I change the image of the `fabric.Image` object attribute src, if I have already made an animation?

Answer (score 21):

You can use `.setElement()` to change the image.

For example, let's say you have a fabricJS image object called `myFabricObect`.

Then, if you have an html image element `<img id="newImage">` on your page, you can load your `myFabricObject` with the `"newImage"` like this:

```
myFabricObject.setElement(document.getElementById("newImage"));
```

You could also create a javascript `Image()` and assign that to `myFabricObject`:

```
var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
    myFabricObject.setElement(img);
}
img.src="myNewImage.png";
```

Comment: You might want to add crossOrigin to your image, after ```var img = new Image();``` add ```img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `setSrc()`:

```js
var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
activeObject.setSrc('images/my-image.png', function(img) {
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is best option I found

```
 var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
 activeObject.setSrc(data.url);
```